# How do I make AJAX listen for changes in my global handler? ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ashx

I have two files: `MenuHandler.ashx` and a page where it handles the `AJAX` for this page.

> `MenuHandler.ashx` - Gets all elements from my database table **and
>   parses it to the `AJAX` function** below;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            loadMenuHandler();


            function loadMenuHandler() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'MenuHandler.ashx',
                    method: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {



                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#menu").empty();
                            buildMenu($('#menu'), data);
                            loadMenuHandler();
                            showCorrectMenu();

                        }, 1000)

                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

Currently, my `AJAX` function rebuilds after every 1 second and any change I make to the database table, the changes are automatically pushed without refreshing the page, **but I believe this to be expensive and inefficient.**

How do I make it so, **only when there is a change to the database or should I say to the MenuHandler.ashx it should run the below functions.**

```
$("#menu").empty();
buildMenu($('#menu'), data);
loadMenuHandler();
showCorrectMenu();
```

Comment: You might want to look into using web sockets, you can also use long poling with aJax, but can be a little tricky.

Comment: WebSockets are a good way to communicate remote changes to your client. [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) polyfills this feature. Your current method is not bad, since it's just polling at 1-second intervals.

Comment: hmm, your comments sounds interesting... is there any solution such that i can check if data !== currentdata then call  those below functions or compare the data that is being built? @ShawnLaFrance